# NSMutablearray addObject is not working it overwrites data

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I'm a beginner to XCode.

1- I have a view with UITableViewCell(FirstViewController)
2- I have another view(SecondViewController) that contains some textfields to get data from user
3- I have to pass this data to the FirstViewController
4- The data is passed successfully to the FirstViewController and successfully added in the TableViewCell
5- but the problem is that....
6- if I add another data, it is added but the previous cell get blanked.
How can I preserve the previous data while saving new one????????

7- temp is variable where data is collected... 
8-here (item) is NSMutablearray.. It adds object(temp) to item using

```
             [self.item addObject:temp ];
```

.. but old value of temp get lost ;(

///my Code

```
     data *temp;
    temp =[[data alloc]init];

    temp.name=NSLocalizedString(textofsub, @"name");
    temp.detail=NSLocalizedString(@"Teacher", @"detail");
    temp.image=@"a.jpg";
    temp.time=NSLocalizedString(@"8:30", @"time");

    [self.item addObject:temp ];    //
    [self.mytableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to initialize array on viewDidLoad

```
   self.item =[[NSMutablearray alloc]init];
```